How to install ubuntu on jetson orin nano
I have nvidia jetson orin. I download ubuntu 20.04 and balenaEtcher to flash ubuntu in microsd card. After flashing the jetson is not start just black screen on monitor
what I want is to flash ubuntu image on jetson orin and then install related cuda driver for deep learning etc. but I am failing to install ubuntu on jetson using conventional way

You didn't actually specify which Ubuntu 20.04 LTS product you downloaded/wrote to thumb-drive; as the link you provided opens offering many ISOs for different architectures; selecting the wrong one would be expected to fail to boot on your selected device. I suggest being specific with what you did, instead of vague links that contain both correct & incorrect images for your specific device..

As jetson orin has Arm Cortex-A78AE. I download ubuntu which is compatible with this processor

I think the problem is with bootloader or etc
